# Pandas Group By Sum Keep Only One of Index as Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
group = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
df = {'population': [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800],
      'city_name': ['Chicago', 'Chicago', 'New York', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'New York'],
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=group)


    city_name   population
A   Chicago     100
A   Chicago     200
A   New York    300
A   New York    400
B   Chicago     500
B   New York    600
B   Chicago     700
B   New York    800
```

Now I want to find the total population grouped by the index and `city_name` Simple enough:

```
total = df.groupby([df.index, 'city_name']).sum()

                 population
    city_name   
A   Chicago        300
    New York       700
B   Chicago        1200
    New York       1400
```

Problem is this returns a multi-level index (I think). What I want is to retain the original index but keep city_name as a column. In other words, what I want is

```
    city_name     population
A   Chicago        300
A    New York      700
B   Chicago        1200
B    New York      1400
```

Now I can achieve what I want by doing something like

```
total.reset_index(inplace=True)
total.set_index(keys='level_0', inplace=True)
```

Since the reset_index takes both indices and puts them as columns and then I can just set one of them back to the index. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `level=1` to [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for reseting only second level of `multiindex`:

```
total.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)
print total
  city_name  population
A   Chicago         300
A  New York         700
B   Chicago        1200
B  New York        1400
```

Or:

```
total.reset_index(level='city_name', inplace=True)
print total
  city_name  population
A   Chicago         300
A  New York         700
B   Chicago        1200
B  New York        1400
```

Comment: Or you can use the level name for better readability, i.e. use `level='city_name'`